# Apex to do POST and Get call and updating the record with response received

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest

I have a trigger which invokes a Apex future class to do a post call and receiving the XML. How i can parse the XML and update the same record with the data recceived ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass parameters to the future method with the Id's of the records that need to be updated by the future method. Slightly modified from the documentation:

```
global class FutureMethodRecordProcessing
{
    @future
    public static void processRecords(List<ID> recordIds)
    {   
         // Get those records based on the IDs
         List<Account> accts = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN :recordIds];


         // Process records, update fiends on Accounts based on callout response

         // Update the records
         update accts;

    }
}
```

Apex also provides methods for processing XML. You could read it using [streams](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_streaming_reading.htm) with a XmlStreamReader.

Or you could work with the [DOM model](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm).